# Create a pie chart in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, chart

How do you create a pie chart of a feature class showing the total area of each feature in it. I'm currently using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1. When I click on the 'Create Chart' button in the Data tab for the feature layer, there is no option for a pie chart. In ArcMap, I would simply go to View>Graph>Create Graph and click on pie chart. Does ArcGIS Pro not have the function to create a pie chart outside of Symbology? I don't want every feature to show a pie, I just want one pie for the feature that I can move around the map as a graphic element.

[image]

Comment: via layer properties https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/layer-properties/chart-symbology.htm

Comment: I don't want a pie chart on each feature, I want one pie chart for the entire feature class representing the total area of each class in one field. Unless I'm mistaken, going through symbology will create multiple pie charts tied to each record in your feature class. I want one pie chart graphic element that I can move to the bottom left corner of the map.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible per the documentation [here](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/pie-chart.htm).

This was not possible previously in ArcGIS Pro, ([ArcGIS Pro v2.9](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/types-of-charts.htm)). As an alternative method, I'd recommend using a Microsoft program, like Word, to create the pie chart and then after saving it as an image, you can insert it into the ArcGIS layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this idea for status updates: https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/add-pie-charts-to-arcgis-pro-tabular-charts/idi-p/922729 This is currently In Product Plan.